# .htaccess: Rewrite Problem

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm creating a website. I have this code in the .htaccess file:
`RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ /redirect.php?id=$1`
But when I go to, for example **/ASEi** it says **404 Not Found**. What's the problem?

Comment: This will turn any URL like /00/, /01/, etc (i.e. two numbers followed by a slash) into /redirect.php?id=00, etc. So the fact that /ASEi gets a 404 is unsurprising unless you actually have a file called ASEi. What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Ooops. But with the answeer @Tim, it doesn't work

Comment: What is redirect.php doing, and what do you want to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, the problem was the first `/`. The .htaccess now looks like: 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ redirect.php?id=$1

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

RewriteRule ^/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ /redirect.php?id=$1